# Editing versioned view in ArcSDE 10.1 error

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I am working in an ArcSDE 10.1 instance sitting on Oracle that I believe was upgraded from a previous ArcSDE version.  It has a versioned view for the table I am trying to edit (specifically, delete rows).  However, the views isn't called *feature_class_name*_vw, which seems to be the naming convention for views generated in 10.1.  Which makes me think that it was created manually in a previous version of SDE.

This is the error I'm getting:

> ORA-20025: State 118977 is closed.
>
> ORA-06512: at "SDE.VERSION_UTIL", line 2495
>
> ORA-06512: at "DATA.V109_DELETE", line 1
>
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DATA.V109_DELETE'

Originally, it was giving a **Not owner of state 0** error.  State 0 is owned by SDE, so that makes sense.  I created an edit session in ArcMap with the same user that I am executing my SQL as, and that generated a state in the DB with the correct user - but also the state is closed error I mentioned above.  So it seems like it isn't generating a state when editing the view.

Any ideas why this is?

**RESOLUTION:**

I asked our DBA to regenerate the versioned views and that did the trick.

Comment: Can you un register the data as versioned and register again?  My thought is that if the name of the view is following the naming convention then it is probably not created by the system.  I wouldn't try to run sql updates/deletes to any versioned data in this view (I doubt it's a versioned view).  What is the sql your trying to run?  Specifically calling the stored procs used for this.

Comment: I agree, it looks like it's looking for a trigger that belonged to the previous version and not the current version... of course it could be a manual trigger but it doesn't exist so it can't be checked.

Comment: The triggers do exist on the view.  In fact, the code that executes the SQL used to work (without any reports of anomalies).  It might be 2 years since I last touched it.  Looking at the DDL for the view, it looks like it is correctly versioned, and it doesn't look like it was created by one of our DBAs.  Not 100% sure on that though.